# drush error - how to apply patch?

Tags: 7, drush

When I try to update modules or clear cache with drush on my local dev machine (Mac OSX) I get the following four times at the beginning of the command result, and it fails.

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() pm.drush.inc:584

My sites are D7, and the drush version is 6.0-beta1.  I can't find what the latest version is anywhere.  Is this it?

I looked on drupal.org and found a patch here: https://drupal.org/node/2041875

But I don't know how to apply a patch to drush. Can anyone point me to that information or tell me how to do it?

Comment: From the command line, it should be: `patch -p0 < file.patch` within the module directory. If the patch are not correct, it'll ask you for the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has a wealth of community documentation related to this:

- [Patch guide](https://drupal.org/patch)
- [Applying patches](https://drupal.org/patch/apply)
- [Applying patches manually](https://drupal.org/node/534548)

However, for your first problem. Drush is pretty much version independant. If you have the latest version of drush it will work with drupal 7, 8 and most likely 6.

Finally, the issue you linked also mention that it's been fixed in the [latest version of drush as well](https://drupal.org/node/2041875#comment-7650619).

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Drush is [6.0.0](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/tag/6.0.0).  Drush has moved to GitHub, so you will need to look for releases there now.  The Drush project on GitHub is https://github.com/drush-ops/drush

Ass chrisjlee said, you won't need to apply the patch you mention above to Drush, as that issue has already been fixed in 6.0.0.  If you'd like help applying patches in the future, though, you might want to try the [drush_iq](https://drupal.org/project/drush_iq) project.  This is a Drush extension that provides useful commands such as `drush iq-apply-patch` and `drush iq-submit`.  Makes applying and submitting patches much easier.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, and I'm glad to know I can download 6.0.0.  But my question (which now doesn't need an answer) was really about patching Drush, not a Drupal project. In all the community documentation and in the drush_iq project, I found nothing about patching Drush itself, and since it's not a module, I didn't think the docs applied. (Granted, when you search for the string 'patch drush' you are likely to get information about using Drush to apply patches to projects, so maybe I missed it.)

Comment: chrisjlee's answer will help you if you need to apply old patches from drupal.org to drush.  And yes, you can use drush_iq to patch drush, but only from old issues still on drupal.org. To apply pull requests from the Drush repository on Github, see the Github documentation (off topic for this forum).